# awk multiple variables for multiple file processing

Tags: awk

I'd like to use awk to process multiple files such as
File 1:

> 1    1.045
>     2    1.033
>     3    1.029

File 2:

> 1    1.078
>    2    1.080
>    3    1.090

but I'm interested in storing a specific field from each file and then printing them all out on one line. For example, I'd like the second field of the second line in both files so that the output would be:

> 1.033    1.080

Can I get awk to store the field in question from each file in a separate variable or in separate fields of an array? I tried:

```
awk '
BEGIN{}
FNR==2{var1=$2;nextfile}
FNR==2{var2=$2}
END{printf "%6.3f    %6.3f\n", var1,var2}' file1 file2
```

but this overwrites var1 with the field from the second file and never processes for var2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the third line is never evaluated, you could solve it like this:

```
awk '
BEGIN{}
FNR==2 && !var1 {var1=$2;nextfile}
FNR==2{var2=$2}
END{printf "%6.3f    %6.3f\n", var1,var2}' file1 file2
```

BUT, this approach is hard to generalize, I would rather do it like this:

```
awk 'FNR==row { printf "%6.3f    ", $col } END { printf "\n" }' row=2 col=2 file1 file2
```

Output:

```
1.033     1.080
```

Answer (score 2):

A different approach:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk 'NR==2{print $2,$4}'
1.033 1.080
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want this?

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$2}' file1 file2
```

outputs:

```
1.045 1.078
1.033 1.080
1.029 1.090
```

Comment: He just wants field 2 of line 2 in each file @Kent

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to try:

```
awk '{p=$2; getline<f} NR==2{print p,$2; exit}' f=file2 file1
```